# Column ... does not belong to table?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm making a application coffee shop management in C#.

I have tables like Bill, BillInfo, Food, FoodCategory, FoodTable and I have 10 FoodTables.

When I click one of the tables then an error occurs

> Column 'DateCheckIn' does not belong to table

My code:

```
//my data
insert Bill(DateCheckIn, DateCheckOut, idTable, status) 
values (GETDATE(), NULL, 1, 0); 
insert Bill(DateCheckIn, DateCheckOut, idTable, status) 
values (GETDATE(), NULL, 2, 0); 
insert Bill(DateCheckIn, DateCheckOut, idTable, status) 
values (GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 2, 1); 

//my code
public Bill(DataRow row)
{
        this.ID = (int)row["id"];
        this.DateCheckIn = (DateTime?)row["DateCheckIn"];

        var dateCheckOutTemp = row["DateCheckOut"];

        if(dateCheckOutTemp.ToString() != "")
            this.DateCheckOut = (DateTime?)dateCheckOutTemp;

        this.Status = (int)row["status"];
}
```

Comment: That mean, `DataRow` you are passing to the `Bill` method from the table which doesn't have `DateCheckIn` column.

Comment: please check schema of 'Bill` table in your db structure.

Comment: create table Bill(
 id int identity primary key,
 DateCheckIn date NOT NULL default getdate(),
 DateCheckOut date,
 idTable int NOT NULL,
 status int NOT NULL default 0 --1: pay || 0: not pay
 --foreign key
 foreign key (idTable) references TableFood(id)
)--I have table Bill, you test that help me

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the required column to your Table.

```
Alter table <TableName> 
add <columnName> <columnType>
```

Comment: That will actually work